# Using the array split method to separate names / numbers

Tags: c#, arrays

I have been instructed to write a program that collects a bowling score (integer) and a name from the user, separated by a space, and sorts each of them into an array using the `Split` method. The output has to be formatted to find the average score and output it to the console, as well as sort the scores (and names) in order of lowest to highest.

I have been able to do everything except find a way to sort the names with their corresponding scores.

Here is what I have so far. To clarify, I need help writing a sorting algorithm for my array of names.

```
using System;

class Program
{
    //class variables
    const int MAX = 10;

    static void Main()
    {
        //declare array
        int[] score = new int[MAX];
        string[] name = new string[MAX];

        //program prologue
        Console.WriteLine("****************Bowling Project****************");
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a name and a score for each player. For example 'John 145'.\nHit enter when you are done.");

        //for loop to get input
        for (int i=0; i<MAX; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a name and a score for player #{0}: ", (i + 1));
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (input == "")
            {

                break; // if nothing is entered, it will break the loop
            }
            //split the user data into 2 arrays (integer and string)
            string[] separateInput = input.Split();
            name[i] = separateInput[0];
            score[i] = int.Parse(separateInput[1]);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\n****************Input Complete****************");

        //calculate the average score and send to the console
        CalculateScores(score);

        Console.WriteLine("The scores for the game are:");

        //sort the scores
        BubbleSort(score);


        Console.ReadLine();
    }//End Main()
    //CalculateScores Method
    //Calculates the average score of an array of integers
    //Takes an array of integers as parameters
    //Returns void
    //Outputs the average to the console
    static void CalculateScores(int[] score)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        int average = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < score.Length; i++)
        {
            sum += score[i];
            average = sum / score.Length;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The average score was {0}", average);
    }//End calculateScores

    //Swap method
    //Takes 2 integers as parameters
    //Switches the value of 2 integers (a and b)
    static void Swap(ref int a, ref int b)
    {
        int temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }

    //BubbleSort method
    //Sorts an array of integers
    //Takes an array of integers as a parameter
    //Returns void
    //Outputs to the console
    static void BubbleSort(int[] score)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < score.Length -1; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < score.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                if (score[i] > score[i + 1])
                {
                    Swap(ref score[i], ref score[i + 1]);
                }
            }
        }
        foreach (int a in score)
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", a);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}//End class Program
```

Comment: Please take your time to format your code properly and the fact that it is homework has no relevance to the question being asked.

Comment: at a quick glimpse: using 2 arrays is a bit weird. but however. If you sort one array for the score, why don't you just swap the same array possition for the player, so that corresponding position with player and score are the same? so instead of ({Swap(ref score[i], ref score[i + 1]);}) ({Swap(ref score[i], ref score[i + 1]);Swap(ref player[i], ref player[i + 1]);})

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time asking a question here in over a year. I didn't even realize that it wasn't formatted properly? Which part is incorrect? thank you

Comment: If you look at the revisions, you will see that the code was interpreted as text and the indentation was uneven.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `names[]` corresponds 1 to 1 with `score[]`:

Just take your `BubbleSort` method, and pass both `names[]` and `score[]` into it

Then, you whenever you do an operation on `score[]` do it on `names[]` too.

something like this

```
static void BubbleSort(int[] score, string[] names)
{

    for (int j = 0; j < score.Length -1; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < score.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (score[i] > score[i + 1])
            {
                Swap(ref score[i], ref score[i + 1]);
                Swap(ref names[i], ref names[i + 1]);
            }
        }
    }
    foreach (int a in score)
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", a);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

you might have to make a `swap` method for strings

```
static void Swap(ref string a, ref string b)
{
    string temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! I actually already tried that, but my bubblesort method only works for integers. I have tried rewriting it the same way with names[] instead of scores[] and replacing int[] with string[], but it won't compile.

Comment: @xavi i've edited my post to clarify what my intention was

Comment: This was fantastic, and worked well. Thank you for mentioning the possibility of creating a separate swap method for strings. I completely overlooked that, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @xavi  I'd like to point out, too, that when you're not constrained by arbitrary homework requirements, the class-based answer that the other posters proposed is actually the correct way to do it.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much the story of my university career. Thanks again mate.

Comment: @SamIam - +1 for the algorithm, but your code will fail as your swap method takes in strings so `score[i]` can't be passed in? :P I'm sure the OP recognises this though

Comment: @Sayse the OP already had a swap method for ints

Comment: ah sorry, didn't scroll that far!

Answer (score 1):

you should make a separate class that will store a player with its score array.

then make an array of players that you can sort based upon their `name`

EDIT: I've updated my answer to be an implemented player class that builds upon your original code. If this is for a university project this may get seen by plagiarism checkers so I'd be wary to use it.

```
public class Player
{
     public Player(){}
     public Player(string name, int score)
     {
         m_name = name;
         m_score = score;
     }
     public Player(Player p)
     {
         m_name = p.Name;
         m_score = p.Score;
     }
     public string Name
     {
         get{return m_name;}
     }
     public int Score
     {
         get{return m_score;}
     }
     private string m_name
     private int m_score
}

Player[] players = new Player[MAX];
static void BubbleSort(Player[] players)
{

    for (int j = 0; j < players.Length -1; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < players.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (players[i].Score > players[i + 1].Score)
            {
                Swap(ref players[i], ref players[i + 1]);
            }
        }
    }
    foreach (Player a in players)
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", a.Score);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
   static void Swap(ref Player a, ref Player b)
    {
        Player temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I had thought about doing that, but I will get points taken away if I don't use .split method.

Comment: @xavi - you still can use the split method? when I read it it sounded like you were reading in strings such as "name 1 2 3", so you instantiate a new player with splitstring[0] for name and then the rest for the scores

Comment: @xavi - for a bit of practice, i'll have a go at writing out an example of how you can use a player class with sam's suggestion. I wouldn't include it in your assignment though as you would likely be pulled up for it. But think you will find it interesting for future :)

Comment: @xavi - My answer now shows an example of how you should look to implement a player class

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using two collections of loosely associated values, use a single collection of a class:

```
public class BowlingScore {

  public string Name { get; private set; }
  public int Score { get; private set; }

  public BowlingScore(string name, int score) {
    Name = name;
    Score = score;
  }

}
```

Use a list rather than an array for the collection:

```
List<BowlingScore> scores = new List<BowlingScore>();
```

In your loop you can create instances of the class and add to the list:

```
BowlingScore item = new BowlingScore(separateInput[0], int.Parse(separateInput[1]);
scores.Add(item);
```

By using a list instead of an array, it will only contain the items that you actually add. Your current code would need another variable to keep track of how many items in the array was actually used, so that you don't include the ones left empty at the end.

Now, as you have the name and score as a single unit, you can sort the list using the same approach as you used for sorting an array, only you compare a property of the objects. As you swap the whole objects, the name will follow the score when you sort on scores, and vice versa.

The items in the list can be accessed using index just like an array, only the length of the list is in the `Count` property instead of `Length`.

Comment: seems very similar to my answer...

Answer (score 0):

No need to create two arrays because you are losing the semantic meaning between the player's name and its score. But also no need to create a new class for that. You can re-use built-in classes/structs like Tuple<...> or KeyValuePair<...>. For ordering, you can use linq-extension methods.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // just some sample players
    const string player1 = "David 100";
    const string player2 = "Jennifer 1430";
    const string player3 = "Eve 234";

    // the string-array with information about players
    var players = new[] { player1, player2, player3 };

    // initialize the array: a tuple is the name of the player and the score
    var scores = new List<Tuple<string, int>>(players.Length);

    foreach (string player in players)
    {
        // split by whitespace
        string[] info = player.Split(' ');

        // be failure tolerant: split must result in at least 2 entries and second one must be integer
        int score;
        if (info.Length <= 2 && int.TryParse(info[1], out score))
            scores.Add(new Tuple<string, int>(info[0], score));
    }

    // print average score
    Console.WriteLine("Average score for {0} players is: {1}{2}", scores.Count, scores.Select(t => t.Item2).Average(), Environment.NewLine);

    // print score of each single player (ordered from highest to lowest score)
    foreach (Tuple<string, int> score in scores.OrderByDescending(t=>t.Item2))
        Console.WriteLine("Player '{0}' => score: {1}", score.Item1, score.Item2);

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```